# Pyspark is taking empty cell value as null when reading from csv

Tags: pyspark

I have a CSV file in which some cells are empty. When I read into the data frame pyspark is taking null for those empty cells. Is there any way to assume open cell data as empty value when reading from a CSV file

```
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("col1",StringType(),nullable=False),
    StructField("col2",StringType(),nullable=False),
    StructField("col3",StringType(),nullable=False)
  ])
file1='file.csv'
df1=spark.read.csv(file1,header=True,schema=schema)
print(df1.show())
#Want result to be -
+----+-----+----+
|col1| col2|col3|
+----+-----+----+
|   1|    2|   3|
|  11|     |  33|
| 111|  222| 333|
| 123|hello|  Hi|
+----+-----+----+
```

Excel file data is[image]-

Comment: It depends what you mean by empty value. Have you tried setting `nullValue`? For example if you want them to be empty strings use `df1=spark.read.csv(file1,header=True,schema=schema, nullValue="")` (that might not be the correct usage as I'm unfamiliar with pyspark but you get the idea)

Comment: as stated in the prev comment, you could change the [`nullValue`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#:~:text=read/write-,nullValue,-Sets%20the%20string) property to a certain string. by default, all blanks are treated as nulls.

Comment: I have tried with nullValue for empty cell value it's showing "null" in output. If cell have no values then for that i want empty string in pyspark dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **nullValue** to whatever value you want it to be.

```
null_value_representation= ""
df1=spark.read.csv(file1,header=True,schema=schema, nullValue= null_value_representation)
```

Comment: I have tried with nullValue but it's not working. It's showing null.

Comment: What is the value you have given for nullValue. If its nullValue="", that will most likely get translated as null. Can you try something like -1 for testing purposes?